# Tensorflow Histogram error

Tags: python, tensorflow, histogram

I new to tensorflow and my code is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
logdir="/tmp/mnist_tutorial5/"
mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.mnist.read_data_sets(train_dir=logdir+"data",one_hot = True)
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.Session()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir)
def model(input):
    w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784,10], stddev=0.1), name="W")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[10]), name="B")
    act = tf.matmul(input,w) + b
    tf.summary.histogram("weights",w)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases",b)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations",act)
return act

def train():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name="input_img")
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name="labels")
    my_label = model(x)
    print("linear_regression is completed")
    mean_error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(my_label-y)))
    tf.summary.scalar("loss", mean_error)
    train_step=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0003).minimize(mean_error)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(my_label, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    summ = tf.summary.merge_all()
    for i in range(2000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        train_accuracy = sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch[0], y: batch[1]})
        print("%s th iteration"%i)
        if i%500==0:
            print("over 2")
            summarys = sess.run(summ, {x: batch[0], y: batch[1]})##i'm getting error here
            print("over 3")
        writer.add_summary(summarys,i)
    print("one over")
train()
writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Nan in summary histogram for: weights
     [[Node: weights = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](weights/tag, W/read)]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- first of all its just a one layer network with no hidden layer
- you have not applied any kind of activation function
- no activation means your outputs are not being squashed
- your gradients are getting exploded because of which the weights during updation are being exploded which may result in nan
- You are training for 2000 epochs which means obviously after few epochs the weights will be nan
- try to use an activation function like sigmoid and add atleast one hidden layer and you will be fine
- also reduce the number of epochs ... For mnist classification you do not need  the model to train for 2000 epochs ... Waste of time

Comment: thanks bro, just now i started to learn machine learning,
i don't know  how to learn
could you please help me bro?

Comment: Hey can I have a up vote so that I cross 500 points :) ... Yeah I mean you can personally message me if you want ... You can follow my channel on youtube that I have started for machine learning  https://youtu.be/YBtQ3Y_lWfQ